# Batch for not issue

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

Hope someone can help me, I running the following script in a sub folder looking for a certain string.  This then exports the text names into a new text document called Completed.txt .  However I'm trying to obtain a text document that does not have the string in them called Incomplete.txt.  This would be easy if I could use a

```
for /f %%i in not
```

But that doesn't exist.

Here is what I have so far.

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('findstr /i "Script" *.txt') do @echo %%i >> Completed.txt
```

I have attempted the following but that has failed.

```
for /f %%i in ('findstr /i "Script" *.txt') do If %errorlevel%=5 @echo %%i >> Error.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is another way. This will loop through the $Directory, add -recurse if you want it to go deeper and only look at files with .txt as an extension.

```
$Directory = "C:\Scripts\*"
$Completed = "C:\Tools\Completed.txt"
$Incomplete = "C:\Tools\Incomplete.txt"

$Files = Get-Childitem -Path $Directory -Include *.txt

Foreach ($File in $Files) {
    $FileContents = Get-Content $File
    if ($FileContents -contains 'Script') {
        Add-Content -Path $Completed -Value $File.Name
    } else {
        Add-Content -Path $Incomplete -Value $File.Name
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for a quick reply.  What I'm searching for is the string 'Script' in  a number of files within 1 folder.  If it finds it then outputs the name of the file to Completed.txt otherwise Incomplete.

Comment: @Alpinestar I updated the answer to do what you asked.

Comment: Just tested the script and it is outputting all the filenames into the Incomplete.txt file.  Seems to completely ignore the contents of the files as I have a number of files containing the Script keyword.

Comment: Interesting works for me.

Answer (score 0):

**find_incomplete.bat**

```
@echo 2>incomplete.txt
@for %%i in (*.txt) do @findstr /i "Script" %%~i > nul || echo %%i >> incomplete.txt
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you wolfevokcats.  The output is clean an only outputs the filename into the txt doc.  If I wanted to amend that for the completed.txt what would I need to change ?

Comment: @Alpinestar, to output only files that have "Script" in them, change `||` to `&&`, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

This batch can did the trick :

```bat
@echo off
set "Complete=Complete.txt"
Set "Incomplete=Incomplete.txt"
If exist "%Complete%" Del "%Complete%"
If exist "%Incomplete%" Del "%Incomplete%"
@for %%i in (*.txt) do (
    @findstr /i "Script" %%~i >nul && echo %%i --^> %%~fi >> "%Complete%" || echo %%i --^> %%~fi >> "%Incomplete%"
)
pause
```